# OpenFST on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio, openfst

I am trying to install OpenFST on Windows, using Visual Studio Express 2013. However, I am not being able to do it.

I also tried on Linux, but it my VM is crashing.

If someone knows how to work on it using Windows, please let me know.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean your VM is crashing?

Answer (score 1):

The openfst.org site now contains contributed code for that:
http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/Contrib/OpenFstWin
But as of now, these are rather outdated.

A newer version is available here, and the authors promise to keep in step with the new opendfst distributions: 
https://github.com/kkm000/openfst